# Composite types with pg-promise

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

Here is an example code:

```
battle.heroes = [{ id: hero.id, name: hero.name }]; //This is my array I want to insert
await db.one('INSERT INTO battles(mode, params, heroes) VALUES(${mode}, ${params}, ${heroes}) RETURNING id', {
    mode: battle.mode,
    params: battle.params,
    heroes: battle.heroes,
});
```

PostgreSQL type 'hero_info':

```
id int4
name varchar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present each array element via [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting), either by extending the existing objects with `rawType` and `toPostgres`, or using your own custom type, like one below:

```
const hero = (id, name) => ({
   rawType: true,
   toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('($1, $2)::hero_info', [id, name])
});
```

Usage example:

```
const heroes = [hero(1, 'first'), hero(2, 'second')];

await db.one('INSERT INTO battles(mode, params, heroes) VALUES(${mode}, ${params}, ${heroes}) RETURNING id', {
    mode: battle.mode,
    params: battle.params,
    heroes
});
```

For the code above, your array of `heros` will be correctly formatted as:

`array[(1, 'first')::hero_info, (2, 'second')::hero_info]`

Comment: And another question here. If I want to select this array from db. How can I map it to get JS representaion of data instead of a string? I'm getting something like "{"(1,HeroName1)","(2,HeroName2)"}" at each value.

Comment: @Arhimondus They are called tuples, aka nightmare, quite difficult to deal with when reading the data back. It is a whole new question, and bigger than this one. Search StackOverflow, there's plenty about it. And it is a subject outside of `pg-promise`.

Comment: @Arhimondus there are no good solutions for tuples, as far as I know. And there will never be, because they are too awkward to work with, and they are considered an obsolete approach. Developers nowadays use JSON instead of tuples. Tuples are now just a legacy.

Comment: Syntax for Custom Type Formatting has been updated, as it changed in [v6.5.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.6.5.0).

Comment: @vitaly-t Why do you think that Custom types in postgres are legacy? They have some advantages over JSON: especially speed and type-safety (on the db-level).

Comment: @TmTron Ever since v10 of PostgreSQL, all the focus was on further improving and optimization of JSON processing, which now (v12) is on another level. Tuples are now kind of old-ish, plus they present a number of hurdles when dealing with them natively, due to convoluted serialization. In all, JSON is the way to go ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t the reason for this, is that JSON is just new and missing a lot of features. Tuples on the other hand exist since a long time and are here to stay. What to use depends on the use-case. e.g. for large time-series tables, using JSON is just going to kill your performance.

Comment: @TmTron It is all individual choice. I only do PostgreSQL development under Node.js these days, where working with tuples is a nightmare, as there is no proper de-serializer for them, while with JSON everything just works.